# Selenium Python Unable to scroll down in tiktok while fetching videos

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory, tiktok

i am trying to use Selenium Python to open tiktok user page and scroll down to load all user videos
i can open the url and get the source code including all loaded videos data, but when scroll down and time sleep for a while and get source code, the page code is the sane with same videos and nothing new is loaded!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok")
time.sleep(20)
#wd.implicitly_wait(10)
#print(wd.page_source)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 20

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return      document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

print(wd.page_source)
```

i also tried to use this code for scroll down

```
wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(10)
print(wd.page_source)
```

but also nothing is loaded in source code!
, i am using google colab, any help?

- update: changed variable "driver" to "wd"
- update: that's the install code for chromium driver

install

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Although I am using `playwright`, with `playwright-stealth`, not `selenium`.

The problem is that tiktok detects that you are headless and throttles you. Or at least that was my problem.

Simply adding a browser flag: **"--headless=new"** fixed it. This argument makes a new recently released version of headless chromium to be used. And this version is much less detectable. Just make sure you use a recent version of chromium.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` you start using an inexistent variable called `driver`, i changed it for `wd` and it scrolled down, but the web showed that there is a problem trying to load from there.

[image]

and the code also throws an error

`[9612:864:0614/164525.919:ERROR:util.cc(127)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater`

I searched this error and it seems to be related to the version of chrome and chromedriver as stated here:https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/uqt9z9/cant_create_base_directory/

That's as far as i achived, hope it helps. :)

Here's my current code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok")
time.sleep(20)
#wd.implicitly_wait(10)
#print(wd.page_source)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 20

# Get scroll height
last_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = wd.execute_script("return      document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

print(wd.page_source)
```

I took out the headless argument to see the results more clearly

Comment: thanks for your help, yes instead of "driver" it should be "wd" i forget to change it, the code  tested in google colab and it work without error but scroll down not load any new videos, also i guess that chrome driver not have a problem since i can use scroll down with google image search without a problem. i updated the post and put the installation code used for google driver

Comment: as i use the code in google colab i must run chrome headless , i tried alternative method to scroll down by send end keys instead of scroll down script, and save_screenshot "wd.save_screenshot('1.png')", and i can see the page scrolled down and also a message say that "some thing went wrong!" but can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: @unknown based on the error `[9612:864:0614/164525.919:ERROR:util.cc(127)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater` that i got i think that selenium is not allowed into a folder whe triying to load. like it wants to sove something to cache.

when i have some free time i'll try some more